# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"?

Tags: matlab

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function[ind]=indices_clima(YY,var,valor);
b=sum(var>=valor,2); %busca los valores mayores o iguales a un valor dado
a=YY((b));
m=unique(a);

for n=1:length(m)
    ind(n)=length( find(b==m(n)));
end

ind=ind';
```

La creé para encontrar valores mayores o iguales a un determinado valor en las filas de una matrix (529x31) y crease un vector que los agrupase por año (YY).

El problema es que en determinadas filas los valores son menores al buscado y me da 0, el cual matlab no considera un valor real, o positivo o lógico y por lo tanto no me permite indexar el vector años(YY), con el vector creado (b).

Me da el error:

> ```
> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals
> ```

**¿Cómo podría modificar (b) para poder indexarlo con el otro vector?**